# Silverlight PDF Viewer

Tags: silverlight, pdf

I want to be able to show PDF docs within my Silverlight 4 application.  I know there is no native support for this and the only real way to do this is to use a third party control.  I’ve looked around and found what looks to be a couple of good options, but they are expensive and somewhat limited.  I don’t know much about PDF docs, but it seems that most of these controls are converting PDFs to something else; such as XOD or XPS.

I am considering writing my own PDF Viewer for my needs, but not sure where to start on something like this.  What would be the best format to convert PDFs to for Silverlight and WPF?  If I could convert to RTF, I could use existing controls to display the document.

I’m assuming since there is such a lack of PDF for Silverlight controls out there that this will not be easy.  Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

You do have one more option besides re-implementing a pdf control.

With a bit of javascript and silverlight's DOM bridge, you can render your PDF in the browser's native pdf plugin and display it in a 'window' over the top of your silverlight application.

This is how many of the 3rd party "web browser" controls for silverlight work as well.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the window does not play well with Silverlight.  Since the window is always on top, you are not able to have any silverlight control interact with it.  Also, having drop down menus and other silverlight elements make using HTML Window really ugly since the window is always on top - even when you want it partially hidden or moved behind another control.  I've gone down that road, but really want something more robust.